# Form not showing, Only the button shows Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to show a newsletter form, and it is not shown in the page

This is my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class newsletter_user(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

This is my **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import newsletter_user

class newsletterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = newsletter_user
        fields = ['email']

        def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            return email
```

This is my **admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import newsletter_user
# Register your models here.
class newsletterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email','date_added',)

admin.site.register(newsletter_user,newsletterAdmin)
```

This is the **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import newsletter_user
from .forms import newsletterForm

# Create your views here.
def newsletter_subscribe(request):
    form = newsletterForm(request.POST or none)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=false)
        if newsletter_user.objects.filter(email=instance.email).exists():
            print("already exists")
        else:
            instance.save()

    context = {'form':form,}
    template = "/blog/templates/footer.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

This is the **html**

```
<form method="post" action=''>
    <div class = "input-group">
        {{form}}  {% csrf_token %}
        <span class = "input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Subscribe</button>

        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name='entry_detail'),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^footer/$', subscribe_views.newsletter_subscribe, name='subscribe'),
]
```

My [Project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTYLs.png)

The button is shown
But the form is not shown..

This is my source in web browser [RIGHT-CLICK->VIEW SOURCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT7kn.png)

Comment: You certainly shouldn't be using the `safe` filter on a form. Does it work if you remove it?

Comment: i added it because it did not

Comment: try {{form.email}}

Comment: What is the resulting html. Use "show source code" in you web browser?

Comment: Where do you define `none`? `form = newsletterForm(request.POST or none)`. This should probably be `None` instead, or it would raise an error. It's important that your question contains the actual code that cases the bug. [mcve]

Comment: @HåkenLid I will edit my post with the result

Comment: Python is case sensitive, so capitalization matters. Python has [recommended naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions). All class names should use "CapWords". `NewsletterUser`, `NewsletterForm`, `NewsletterAdmin` etc. (This will not solve your bug, but following the convention makes the code more readable for us, since your question has a lot of code)

Comment: Hmm Thanks for the advice, Will follow it from now

Comment: Try changing `{{form}}` in your template to `{{ form | default: "missing" }}` to confirm that `form` is not missing from the context.

Comment: Also try to include the `{% debug %}` template tag to get additional debug data. If you have multiple similar view functions, url routes and templates, you might actually be using some other view or template, and not the one you expect.

Comment: @HåkenLid when i add {{ form | default: "missing" }} it throws a template syntax exception

Comment: Show your URLs and state which URL you are actually going to. Also, that source cannot be from that template, as there is extra HTML shown - where is that coming from?

Comment: @DanielRoseman added my urls.py in the post

Comment: Sorry. There should be no space after the `:`. Try `{{ form | default:"missing" }}`

Comment: And is this actually happening when you go to the /footer URL? It does seem strange to have a separate URL for a "footer".

Comment: @DanielRoseman this is how i include my footer.html in index.html...The footer I use it in all pages {% include 'footer.html' %}

Comment: @HåkenLid I still get the exception

Comment: But that makes absolutely no sense at all. You're including the template, but how are you expecting the view to be called? Django only calls the view for the URL you are actually on.

Answer (score 2):

The url router will send the request to the first matching view. That is the only one that is called, and that view has to provide the context data that the template consumes. (You can also write your own [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) to insert context that you need everywhere.)

Since another pattern also matches `/footer/`, your request is clearly handled by some other view.

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name='entry_detail'),
```

If the other view doesn't provide `form` into the context, there's nothing for Django to render.

Your view function `newsletter_detail()` is not called from other views, so that context is not used. (Using the undefined `none` there would have caused a run time error, which shows that the code was never evaluated.)

Catch-all routes such as `entry_detail` should either be used as the last url route, or be made more specific. Something like `r'^/blog/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$'`, for instance, which will not match `/footer/`.

For a simple "subscribe" form in the footer, I recommend writing it as just html, and set up a route `/subscribe/` to handle POST requests. There's not anything to gain by using Django's form framework for such a simple case (Just one field).

[The django docs has an example of how you can implement something like this.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form)

You `footer.html` template fragment should not require any context that is not automatically inserted by a context processor. Django's CsrfViewMiddleware provides the `{% csrf_token %}`, so that's an example of something you can use in template fragments such as a footer.

If you need some complicated form in your footer, you can write custom middleware to insert a Django Form instance in every context, (but you should probably give it a less generic name than `form`).

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: If you want this form to show on every page, you should either use a context processor to include your Form instance. Or you could just write the form as plain html. Make sure that your form's `action` sends the POST to a view that can handle the form data.

Comment: For a simple "subscribe" form in the footer, I recommend writing it as just html, and set up a route `/subscribe/` to handle POST requests. There's not anything to gain by using django's form framework for such a simple case (Just one field). The django docs has an example that is similar. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form

Most websites would also use ajax for this kind of functionality. Once you get this working, you could try to implement it with ajax, so that there's no page refresh required for visitors using the `subscribe` form.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to make some changes in your view somewhat like this,

```
def newsletter_subscribe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = newsletterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            instance = form.save(commit=false) 
            if newsletter_user.objects.filter(email=instance.email).exists(): 
                print("already exists") 
            else: 
                instance.save() 
    else:
        form = newsletterForm()
    context = {'form':form,} 
    template = "/blog/templates/footer.html" 
    return render(request, template, context)
```

You only need to initialise the form with `request.POST` , if request method is actually "POST". Else, just initialise a blank form.

Comment: how is it possible that this guy can down vote anyway?